# Cut video via ffmpeg so that timecode of the first frame will remain

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcode

I am slicing subclips using ffmpeg 5.1 and the command `ffmpeg -ss 5 -i input -t 10 -c copy -y output`
I want my subclip to start at 5 seconds instead of 0 seconds. Is there an option in ffmpeg to implement this logic?

Comment: you can try `-copyts`

Comment: It didn't work for me. Besides, I lost the video from the resulting subclip, only the sound is left.